# PHP mysql not matching individual words

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a simple recommendation engine in php for a digital library application. The recommendation engine uses keywords to make suggestions. The problem is, It doesn't suggest books unless the keywords inputted are exactly the same. for example, book A keyword = "money investment", book B keyword = "money trading"; If I read book A, it doesn't suggest book B to me because the keywords are slightly different. I want it to suggest books as far as there is at least one matching word in the keywords.

```
function getrecommendations(){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT keywords FROM books WHERE Id = ".$_GET['id']."";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $keyword = preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]|\xC3[\x80-\x96\x98-\xB6\xB8-\xBF]|\xC5[\x92\x93\xA0\xA1\xB8\xBD\xBE]){4,}/', $row['keywords'],$match_arr);
    $keyword = $match_arr[0];        
    $i = 0;
        $query ="";
        foreach($keyword as $value)
        {
          if($i==0)
          {
              $query = "'%$value%'";
              $i=1;
          }
            else
            {
         $query = $query . " AND keywords LIKE '%$value%'";  
            }
        }
        $key = $query;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE keywords LIKE $key";
        $result = query($sql);
        confirm($result);
        $no=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($no==0){

        }else{
        echo "<p><b><big><big>RECOMMENDED FOR YOU</big></big></b></p>";
        echo "<hr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
$book = <<<MYHERODOC
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="container2">
                <img style="height:383px; width:254px" src="img/pic_book/{$row['pathtoimage']}" alt="Avatar" class="image img-responsive">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text" style="text-transform:capitalize"><b>{$row['Title']}</b><br><small><small><span style="text-transform:lowercase">by</span> {$row['Author']}</small></small>
                        <a class = "btn overlay-btn" href="book.php?id={$row['Id']}"> Preview </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><br>
            <a href="book.php?id={$row['Id']}" style="color:#cdae51; text-transform:uppercase">{$row['Title']}</a><br>
            <p style="color:#262626">{$row['Author']}</p>     
        </div>
MYHERODOC;
echo $book;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: For recommendation engines you're going to need something more robust than exact word matching. This is usually done with a graph system where words can have rough equivalents with different weights, some of which are contextual. Not everyone will use the same exact term.

Answer (score 0):

```
$title_words = explode(" ", $book_title);
```

This way you can split the full book title in words. So you can match any word in any book title.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a very good full text indexing system which should have been your first port of call. This breaks the rules of normalisation in a much more consistent and transparent way than you have employed here.

However building a system to handle associations between words such as "investment" and "trading" will require a massively more complex system than you are currently building.